# regular expression for currency text-box

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using below regular expression for my validation. But I have issue with this.

```
 <input 
    type="text" 
    class="form-control" 
    ng-pattern="/^((?=.*[1-9]|0)(?:\d{1,3}))((?=.*\d)(?:\.\d{3})?)*((?=.*\d)(?:\,\d\d){1}?){0,1}$/" 
    ng-pattern-err-type="amountMinValue"
    ng-model="dividendIncome.dividendIncome"
    id="dividendIncomeVal"
    placeholder="Dividend Income"
    required
/>
```

When I enter **322@**, validation is not working. But validation is working well for **@322**. Also, user can not enter zero.

How can i modify my regular expression ?

Comment: What do you need to match your expression? What formats do you need to catch?

Comment: user can enter numbers (currency), with decimal point and thousand separator

Comment: Do you also need to have the currency in the value? I didn't understand that. Could you please confirm the exact format you need?

Answer (score 0):

You could use this regex: `^\d+(\.\d{3})*(\,\d+)?$`

The given regex matches the following:

```
10,11
10
1.000.000,11
1.000.000
1.000.000.000.000.000.000.000,00
1.000.000.000.000.000.000.000
```

And if you need to have as a thousand operator the comma *(,)* then you could use this regex: `^\d+(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?$`

The last regex could match all the following:

```
10.11
10
1,000,000.11
1,000,000
1,000,000,000,000,000,000,000.00
1,000,000,000,000,000,000,000
```

If you also need to match currencies, then you could use the following regex that could match currencies at from or the end of the amount with or without spaces:

```
^([\$€£]*\s*)?\d+(,\d{3})*(\.\d+)?([\s\$€£]*)?$
```

Keep in mind, that you should update the currency list you want to use inside the brackets. If for example, you need to validate also Yen, you should update the brackets from `[\$€£]` to `[\$€£¥]` both at the start and the end of the regex.

PS: Unfortunately I cannot help you with the angular part, as I am not an angular developer, but if you replace the line:

```
ng-pattern="/^((?=.*[1-9]|0)(?:\d{1,3}))((?=.*\d)(?:\.\d{3})?)*((?=.*\d)(?:\,\d\d){1}?){0,1}$/"
```

by this

```
ng-pattern="/^\d+(\.\d{3})*(\,\d+)?$/"
```

it should do the work you want.